# Website hosted in IIS not Working

Tags: networking, dns, domain, iis

I hosted a website under default website in IIS and tried to  access it. It worked fine. but when i tried to host it as a separate website i am unable To access the site. I get the below error

"HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied. "

Hosted Servers domain name                 : domain-dev.com

type of authentication used                : Windows Authentication

domain name of the user accessing the site : domain.com (its different from the hosted Servers domain name)

steps followed while hosting application as Separate website

- Right click on Sites And select "add website".
- gave FSApp as site name. Selceted app pool. gave the path.
- in binding left Type and Port unaltered selected the servers ip address in the ip section gave host name as "fuapp.domain.com"
- checked start website immediately. then Clicked on OK.

Now after creating this when i tried To  access the application, a pop up appears asking for user credentials. I tried to logging with my credentials (domain/[my user name])
After three attempts it shows the above said error.
(I logged into the hosted server with the same user name with which i tried to access the site)

Answer (score 0):

Windows authentication depends on that user having permissions to view the directory you are sharing in IIS.  When users are being prompted for credentials they will have to enter a login/password combo that is listed on the permissions for the folder you are sharing in IIS.

Let's say you wanted to share c:\www and use Windows Authentication in IIS.   Let's say you have a user named 'user' added to your windows domain (active directory).   In order to make this work, you will have to do the following:

1. right click on the c:\www folder in Windows Explorer
2. Click on the Security tab
3. Click Edit where it says to change permissions, click Edit
4. Click Add
5. In the add dialog, make sure the context is set to your Windows Domain
6. type 'user' (without ' ') into the search dialog
7. Click Check Names
8. Click OK
9. Depending on the level of access you want to give the 'user' account to your website, apply appropriate permissions.   I strongly suggest giving only Read & Execute, List folder contents and Read permissions.
10. Click OK

Now, if you login to your computer using this 'user' account (you can actually replace user with your network login if you want, just be sure to replace user with your username in all previous steps)  and fire up Internet Explorer, internet explorer should pass on the information regarding the fact that you are logged in via the User account and not even prompt you to enter any credentials.

If you are using Firefox or Chrome, you will have to type in credentials 'domain\user' for the username and whatever password you assigned to this account and it should let you in.

Please let me know if I got any of the details regarding your question wrong.